# Avoid multiple queries to tables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have list of two hospitals key-value selections in params[:hospitals],I am trying to write a query to get conditions row from Condition using params[:hospital] in the query below.

```
params[:hospitals].each do |hospital, xyz|
      <!--code -->
     Condition.find_by_hospital_id(Hospital.find_by_hospital_name(hospital).id)//query
```

Params contains

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"",
 "client"=>{"Client1"=>"1"},
 "hospital"=>{"hospital1"=>"Client1", "hospital2" => "client2"},
 "type"=>"BOTH",
 "beg-dt-tm"=>"",
 "datepicker"=>"",
 "end-dt-tm"=>"",
 "controller"=>"",
 "action"=>""}
```

My question : Is there any better way to write a query by avoiding multiple calls to tables

Thanks

Comment: Are the two models related?  If one `belongs_to` the other, you can use `includes` to pick up the children.

Answer (score 4):

If a Hospital has_many Conditions:

```
class Hospital < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :conditions
end
```

Then you should be able to load everything in a single query:

```
hospitals = Hospital.where(hospital_name: params[:hospitals]).includes(:conditions)

hospitals.each do |hospital|
  # no further SQL queries will be run, because the conditions have been preloaded
  hospital.conditions.each do |condition|
    # do something with this condition
  end
end
```

Comment: This may still end up as two queries because the included association may be fetched as a separate query to the `Hospital.where`. However, that isn't problematic (and indeed may be more efficient) - just in case you see more than one query going on.

Answer (score 2):

Just make two queries. First to load all hospitals by their names and the second to load all hospital conditions. It should seems something like:

```
hospitals = Hospital.where(hospital_name: params[:hospitals])
conditions = Condition.where(hospital_id: hospitals)
```

In this case only two query to DB will be executed.

Comment: I have run it in the rails  console for two hospital selections, the following are the queries ran 1) SELECT "HOSPITALS".* FROM "HOSPITALS"  WHERE "HOSPITALS"."HOSPITAL_NAME" IN ('hsp1', 'hsp2') 2)SELECT "CONDITIONS".* FROM "CONDITIONS"  WHERE "CONDITIONS"."HOSPITAL_ID" IN (SELECT "HOSPITALS"."ID" FROM "HOSPITALS"  WHERE "HOSPITALS"."HOSPITAL_NAME" IN ('hsp1', 'hsp2')), so are we making 3 requests to tables?

Comment: It is only running 3 queries because of the console itself. When you enter the `hospitals = ` row it will execute the query because it wants to show you the value of `hospitals` in the console. It then runs the hospitals query again as part of the `conditions = ` query.

If you have those two statements in your application code, or in a test, you should only see two queries executed.